# 'More' menu is not shown on branch view in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, branch

The 'More' menu doesn't appear when we are on a branch view of a project.
I use Sonarqube 6.7.2.
On master:
[image: master view]

On branch: 
[image: branch view]

Comment: This is because there's nothing to show on branches

Comment: There are the same measures on the branches as on the master, so why can't we show them in a custom page? I understand it for the administration menu but for the custom pages, it would be great to have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

The support of branches features was not implemented to work with custom page extensions, that's why there is no "More" menu for branches.

If you'd like to see this feature implemented, feel free to create a topic in the "[Suggest new features](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/suggestions/features)" section of the community forum.